# Unexpected characters injected when copying from clipboard to vim in terminal

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I'm using OS X 10.14/Vim 8.0.1283 and iTerm2. Every time when I'm copying things from clipboard to terminal, in specific iTerm2, there will be some unexpected characters injected in. 
Say I'm copying `Explore Our Questions` from clipboard to terminal, it ends up being `[200~Explore Our Questions[201~]]`. 
I'm very confused about where are these `[200~` and `[201~]]` from. Can anyone help? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `:set paste` before pasting?
see `help paste`